# How to see the ES6 code of a 3rd party library

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Sometimes I would like to observe the original ES6 code of a 3rd party library - one of those I mention in the package.json, but all I see is probably the ES5 code after Babel transpilation.

For Example:
In the code when I do:

```
import {CardHeader} from "material-ui";
```

And then trying to "go to Decleration" in the IDE I see transpiled code that means nothing to me.

Is there a way to see the original ES6 code?

Comment: Make sure to compile it with a sourcemap enabled.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts for a start I don't mean the code in the chrome debugger but in the IDE. I've updated my question, Thanks.

Comment: To be fair, both your title and question were originally phrased with "debug". Now that you've edited, that's a completely different question.

Comment: just use github, most of the libraries dont publish a non-es5 version.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I've noticed the easiest way is usually to google the source.

Googling "github material-ui cardheader" leads me to https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/CardHeader/CardHeader.js which looks about right...